# Accessing thread from other rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm working on an application, but at the moment I'm stuck on multithreading with rails.

I have the following situation: when some action occurs (it could be after a user clicks a button or when a scheduled task fires off), I'm starting a separate thread which parses some websites until the moment when I have to receive the SMS-code to continue parsing. At this moment I make Thread.stop.

The SMS-code comes as a POST request to some of my controllers. So I want to pass it to my stopped thread and continue its job.

But how can I access that thread?

Where is the best place to keep a link to that thread?

So how can I handle multithreading? There may be a situation when there'll be a lot of threads and a lot of SMS requests, and I need to somehow correlate them.

Answer (score 0):

For all real purposes you can't, but you can have that other thread 'report' its status.

You can use redis-objects to create either a lock object using redis as its flag, create some type of counter, or just true, false value store. You can then query redis to see the corresponding state of the other thread, and exit if needed.

https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects

The cool part about this is it not only works between threads, but between applications.